# How to add maven jar file to docker container

Tags: docker, sbt, maven-3, dockerfile

I have a java docker container which was running fine. But to instrument i have added a new jvm parameter "javaagent" while running the jar file. But the jar file is not present inside the docker container, instead it is in remote maven repository. How to add the maven jar file to the docker container so that while running the jar file i can pass the javaagent path.

```
java -jar -javaagent:"/Users/xxx/work/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar"  ./target/scala-2.11/test-1.0.jar
```

Is there any way i can add this file from maven(not from my local system) to the docker container ?

Answer (score 0):

In you `Dockerfile` you can use the `COPY` command

Example

```
COPY ./aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar /container/folder
```

Now the `jar` will be available on your docker container.

Answer (score 0):

With SBT you can add the following settings in your project config:

```
.settings(
  retrieveManaged := true,
  libraryDependencies += "org.aspectj" % "aspectjweaver" % aspectJWeaverV)
```

AspectJ weaver JAR will be copied to `./lib_managed/jars/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/aspectjweaver-[aspectJWeaverV].jar` in your project root.

Then you can refer this JAR in your `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY ./lib_managed/jars/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/aspectjweaver-*.jar /app-workdir/aspectjweaver.jar
WORKDIR /app-workdir
CMD ["java", "-javaagent:aspectjweaver.jar", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```